# Qual è il ruolo di "si" in questo testo?

Tags: word-usage

Nel racconto *Il pugno chiuso*, di Arrigo Boito, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> V’ha chi sostiene che questa malattia de’ capelli sia epidemica, adducendo ad esempio alcune località lungo la Vistola che ne sono infestate; altri asseriscono che sia prodotta dall’immondezza dei contadini polacchi e dall’uso tradizionale fra quelle genti del tener lunghe le chiome. Una prova in favore di questa seconda opinione **si** è che la plica apparisce come un flagello esclusivo della più bassa plebe, della più lorda genìa dei *servi*, dei vagabondi, dei mendicanti. L’avere la plica è in Polonia un titolo per dimandare l’elemosina.

Non capisco il ruolo di questo "si" che appare nel testo. La frase non dovrebbe essere "Una prova in favore di questa seconda opinione è che la plica apparisce [...]", senza il "si"? Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direi proprio che abbia solo il “valore prevalentemente rafforzativo” di cui parla la [voce “si” del dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/si1/) al punto 3.b. In questo è un uso simile a quelli (esemplificati lì e relativamente frequenti in altri tempi) di “si tacque” o, ancor più, “non sa quel che si dica”, dove “si” si potrebbe omettere senza cambiare il significato.

Nella frase di Boito, in più, contribuisce forse il fatto che subito prima di “è” viene una parola che finisce per “-e”, e il “si” contribuisce a una migliore scansione del periodo.

Comment: Ah, OK: adesso capisco, @DaG. Vedo che il [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI18/01048.jpg) fa esempi simili di Brunetto Latini («Là dove è la lettera 
grossa si è il testo di Tullio, e la lettera sottile sono le parole de lo spositore») e di Vittorio Alfieri («Occupazione mia continua si è lo studio davvero, per quanto però ri­guarda belle lettere»).